# How would I go about adding libraries to iOS app

Tags: swift, xcode, github

Im brand new to iOS development, and Im in a conundrum. I need to add an iOS library from Github into my project to use. However, it does not support Carthage or CocoaPods.

I have tried dragging and dropping the source files into my project, but have had no luck. Ive even tried dragging the entire 'Source' folder into the project, but with the same results.The most common error occurs when I have added the files into my file structure like so:

[image: My folder structure]

The error is: Cannot find MathExprParser in scope.

The link to the Git repo is this: https://github.com/softyde/MathExprParser.

I don't really know what Im doing in this respect, Im used to using CocoaPods and Cartfile...

Note Parser.swift, Scanner.swift, and String+Char.swift are the files in question.
EXPRTESTING is my main project, not part of a workspace.

Comment: I see that the repo includes a Xcode project.  What does it build?

Comment: I have tried building the project, it succeeds, but I cannot find any output.

Answer (score 0):

This was unfortunately, an act of stupidity... =(

According to the repo, you have to copy and past some items into the project structure. I copied the entire folder MathExprParser into my project.

Now, I had tried this before, but I was hung up on trying to import the MathExprParser module.

I realized that since the classes I needed to use were physically inside the project, I didn't need to import it, or use MathExprParser.Parse. I could use just Parse().